# Read Date as string from excel using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to use apache poi library for reading the excel. I want to convert the date field to String value. Hence I used the following code:

```
if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
    if(DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)){
       DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
       FormulaEvaluator fe = Workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
       String str= formatter.formatCellValue(cell, fe);
       return str;
    }
}
```

I am getting Dates in weird form that is <3/12/[]15>. The cell value id 3/12/2015. Can anyone please guide me in this.

Comment: have you tried with cell.getDateCellValue());

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the DateFormatter simply rewrite like this:

```
if(cell.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
    String date = cell.getDateCellValue();
   }
}
```